# Haskell: find out how many bytes a Get expression would consume

Tags: haskell, deserialization

I am writing a tool which includes a deserialization mechanism for my bachelor thesis, for which I use the `Get` Monad ([`Data.Binary.Get`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.4.1/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html)). I ran into the following problem:

During deserialization, there is a part where I have a getter of type `Get a` and I need to read a `ByteString` of length `n`, where `n` is the amount of bytes that would be consumed if I ran my `getter` at this position. In other words, I need to know how much bytes my `getter` would consume without consuming them.

There is a way to do this:

```
readBytes :: Get a -> Get ByteString
readBytes getter = do safe <- lookAhead getRemainingLazyByteString
                      let info = runGetOrFail getter safe
                      -- n_cB = number of consumed bytes
                      case info of Right (_, n_cB, _) -> getLazyByteString n_cB
```

But this is hideous beyond description. Every time this method is called, it copies the entire remainder of the file.

Even though this doesn't seem like a hard problem in theory, and so far the Get Monad has been capable of doing everything I needed, I cannot find a better solution.

Comment: Do you use `binary` or `cereal`? Which `Get` monad do you use?

Comment: I use Data.Binary.Get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know how much bytes my getter would consume without
>   consuming them.

Perhaps you could perform two calls to the `bytesRead :: Get Int64` function, the second call inside a `lookAhead`, after having parsed the `a` value. Something like

```
bytesRead1 <- bytesRead 
bytesRead2 <- lookAhead (getter *> bytesRead)
return (bytesRead2 - bytesRead1)
```

I'm not sure about how `bytesRead` behaves inside `lookAhead`, however.

Comment: That works! (I am still fairly new to Haskell and wasn't familiar with the Applicative functions.) Thanks a lot.